# How to find out the number of fields in a certain line using awk?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

How to find out the number of fields in a certain line using `awk`, and if there is only one field, I want to add something to the end of that line?

```
$ cat myFile
0: stackoverflow com
1: w3 org
2:
3: wikipedia org
4:
```

I want the output like this:

```
$ cat myFile
0: stackoverflow com
1: w3 org
2: NULL
3: wikipedia org
4: NULL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a test for the number of fields:

```
awk 'NF==1 { print $0, "NULL"; next }1' file
```

Results:

```
0: stackoverflow com
1: w3 org
2: NULL
3: wikipedia org
4: NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{if (NF==0){print "NULL"}else print $0}' /tmp/myFile
stackoverflow com
w3 org
NULL
wikipedia org
NULL
```

`NF` is the awk special variable meaning Number(of)Fields. This would be the NumberOfFields that have values in them. You can change the value compared to `NF==1` if your data really has numbered lines. I had assumed this was an artifact of using a numbering utility or editor.

The `else` statement means "any record with NOT zero # of fields, and as such will print records with 1 or more fields.

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` answer (I know I'm off-topic):

```
sed 's/^\([[:digit:]]\+:\)[[:space:]]*$/& NULL/g' myFile
```

A bash answer (still off-topic):

```
while read -a a; do
    if [[ -z "${a[1]}" ]]; then
        echo "$a NULL"
    else
        echo "${a[@]}"
    fi
done < myFile
```

*There's more than one way to skin a cat!*

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}!$2{$2=" NULL"}1' file
```

test:

```
kent$  cat test.txt 
0: stackoverflow com
1: w3 org
2:
3: wikipedia org
4:


kent$  awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}!$2{$2=" NULL"}1' test.txt
0: stackoverflow com
1: w3 org
2: NULL
3: wikipedia org
4: NULL
```